# Send data to Azure Application Insights via Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-application-insights

Actually i try to send metrics data from application gateway to application insights.
Our data is currently still on the German cloud in which Application Insights is not available.
Therefore, our data is logged into our Cloud in Western Europe in Application Insights.
Currently I want to make the values from the metrics of the Application Gateway available in Application Insights

I created a script which was working in a similar way before when i send data from the service bus to Application Insights.

Here is the Script:

```
################################################################################################

$client=New-Object Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient  
$client.InstrumentationKey=$[our app insights instrumentation key]

$timenow = get-date -Format h:mm:s
$timeminus2 = get-date -Format h:mm:s ((get-date).AddMinutes(-1))

$azmetric = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId "[path of Application Gateway]" -MetricName "UnhealthyHostCount", "Throughput", "HealthyHostCount", "TotalRequests", "AvgRequestCountPerHealthyHost", "FailedRequests", "ResponseStatus", "CurrentConnections" -StartTime $timeminus2 -EndTime $timenow

$array1 = $azmetric.Data.Average
$array2 = $azmetric.Name.Value

[int]$max = $array1.Count
if ([int]$array2.count -gt [int]$array1.count) { $max = $array2.count; }

$Results = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $max; $i++)
{
  Write-Verbose "$($array1[$i]),$($array2[$i])"
  [PSCustomObject]@{
    Metric = $array2[$i]
    Data = $array1[$i]
  }
}

$client.TrackMetric($Results)

################################################################################################
```

I receive this message:

For "TrackMetric" and the following number of arguments no overload can be found: "1".
In C:\temp\Powershell\Function\ApplicationGateway\test2.ps1:65 Sign:1
+ $client.TrackMetric($Results)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

i think the problem is that the system can't define what the value of the data is.

Comment: the bigger question for me is why do you need the data in application insights at all?  the metrics are already in azure, you can get to them with other tools in the portal. why do you need the extra hop of taking data out of one place and putting it into AppInsights in the other place at all?

Comment: The Intention to do that was to be able to set up a Dashboard on the one side and create a  custom alert based on These metrics.
When you know a more elegant way, to do this, I am open for Input :)

Answer (score 1):

Which version of TrackMetric are you expecting to call?  because looking at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.telemetryclient.trackmetric?view=azure-dotnet

shows only one method that takes one arg:  TrackMetric(MetricTelemetry), and that metric+data object you are creating is not a metric telemetry object, which has a lot more properties. (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.datacontracts.metrictelemetry?view=azure-dotnet)

you could possibly switch to calling the `TrackMetric(string name, double value)` version of the method like `TrackMetric($array2[$i], $array1[$i], null)`

that would require that call to `TrackMetric` being inside your loop though.

another option would be to use the newer [`getMetric`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.telemetryclient.getmetric?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ApplicationInsights_TelemetryClient_GetMetric_System_String_System_String_) stuff to get the metric inside the loop, and use something like `getMetric(name).TrackValue(value)` instead.  that metric trackvalue will do things to accumulate values over time and create a "pre-aggregated" value instead of sending potentially hundreds or thousands of values one at a time.

the other option though is to not do this at all.  the metrics are *already in azure*, why are you pulling them out and putting them into an application insights resource, potentially losing the correct time values of the original metrics value?

it might be worth updating your question to explain why you are doing what you're doing, because the right answer might be using some other feature of azure (log analytics?  metrics tools?  workbooks?) to query this data out in another existing form instead of creating it, exporting it, importing it back in.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, we can see the data in the metrics in Azure Germany. The problem is that the features are so limited that no real monitoring or alerting is possible. That's why we have Application Insights on our Azure Cloud in Western Europe. The only way we found to solve this so far was to retrieve the data and make it available with the Instrumentation Key in Application Insights. Therefore we wrote a Powershell script.

In fact, we solved this as follows.

Here is the script:

```
# <#
#   .SYNOPSIS
#       read Application Gateway metrics
#   .DESCRIPTION
#       read out application gateway metrics and write data in application insights 
#   .PARAMETER applicationinsightskey
#         application insights key
#   .PARAMETER ResourceId
#         application gateway path
#   .LEGENDE
#       UHC = UnhealthyHostCount
#       TP = Throughput
#       HHC = HealthyHostCount
#       TR = TotalRequests
#       ARH = AvgRequestCountPerHealthyHost
#       FR = FailedRequests
#       RS = ResponseStatus
#       CC = CurrentConnections      
# #>
############################################################################### TIMER ########################################################################################

param (
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true)] 
            [string]$Timer
    )
############################################################################### Service Principal User anmelden ##############################################################
$env:azureAplicationId
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $env:sppassword -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($env:azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)
Connect-AzAccount -Environment AzureGermanCloud -Subscription WKTAADE-PROD-OC -Credential $psCred -TenantId $env:azureTenantId -ServicePrincipal
############################################################################### Application Insight Information ###############################################################
$client = New-Object Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient  
$client.InstrumentationKey = $env:applicationinsightskey
############################################################################### Define Time ###################################################################################
$timenow = get-date -Format h:mm:s
$timeminus1 = get-date -Format h:mm:s ((get-date).AddMinutes(-1))
############################################################################### ----------- ###################################################################################


############################################################################### Get DATA - UnhealthyHostCount #################################################################
$azmetricUHC = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $env:resourceId -MetricName "UnhealthyHostCount" -StartTime $timeminus1 -EndTime $timenow
############################################################################### Put DATA into Array ###########################################################################
$valuesUHC = $azmetricUHC.Data.Average 
$namesUHC = $azmetricUHC.Name.Value | Out-String
############################################################################### LOOP - Send to Application Insights ###########################################################
foreach ($nameUHC in $namesUHC)
{
  foreach ($valueUHC in $valuesUHC)
     {
        $outputUHC = $nameUHC
        Write-Host $outputUHC

        $client.TrackMetric($outputUHC, $valueUHC)
        $client.Flush()
    } 
}
############################################################################### Get DATA - Throughput ########################################################################
$azmetricTP = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $env:resourceId -MetricName "Throughput" -StartTime $timeminus1 -EndTime $timenow
############################################################################### Put DATA into Array ##########################################################################
$valuesTP = $azmetricTP.Data.Average 
$namesTP = $azmetricTP.Name.Value | Out-String
############################################################################### LOOP - Send to Application Insights ##########################################################
foreach ($nameTP in $namesTP)
{
  foreach ($valueTP in $valuesTP)
     {
        $outputTP = $nameTP
        Write-Host $outputTP

        $client.TrackMetric($outputTP, $valueTP)
        $client.Flush()
    } 
}
############################################################################### Get DATA - HealthyHostCount ##################################################################
$azmetricHHC = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $env:resourceId -MetricName "HealthyHostCount" -StartTime $timeminus1 -EndTime $timenow
############################################################################### Put DATA into Array ##########################################################################
$valuesHHC = $azmetricHHC.Data.Average 
$namesHHC = $azmetricHHC.Name.Value | Out-String
############################################################################### LOOP - Send to Application Insights ##########################################################
foreach ($nameHHC in $namesHHC)
{
  foreach ($valueHHC in $valuesHHC)
     {
        $outputHHC = $nameHHC
        Write-Host $outputHHC

        $client.TrackMetric($outputHHC, $valueHHC)
        $client.Flush()
    } 
}
############################################################################### Get DATA - TotalRequests #####################################################################
$azmetricTR = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $env:resourceId -MetricName "TotalRequests" -StartTime $timeminus1 -EndTime $timenow
############################################################################### Put DATA into Array ##########################################################################
$valuesTR = $azmetricTR.Data.Total
$namesTR = $azmetricTR.Name.Value | Out-String
############################################################################### LOOP - Send to Application Insights ##########################################################
foreach ($nameTR in $namesTR)
{
  foreach ($valueTR in $valuesTR)
     {
        $outputTR = $nameTR
        Write-Host $outputTR

        $client.TrackMetric($outputTR, $valueTR)
        $client.Flush()
    } 
}
############################################################################### Get DATA - AvgRequestCountPerHealthyHost ######################################################
$azmetricARH = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $env:resourceId -MetricName "AvgRequestCountPerHealthyHost" -StartTime $timeminus1 -EndTime $timenow
############################################################################### Put DATA into Array ###########################################################################
$valuesARH = $azmetricARH.Data.Average 
$namesARH = $azmetricARH.Name.Value | Out-String
############################################################################### LOOP - Send to Application Insights ###########################################################
foreach ($nameARH in $namesARH)
{
  foreach ($valueARH in $valuesARH)
     {
        $outputARH = $nameARH
        Write-Host $outputARH

        $client.TrackMetric($outputARH, $valueARH)
        $client.Flush()
    } 
}
############################################################################### Get DATA - FailedRequests #####################################################################
$azmetricFR = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $env:resourceId -MetricName "FailedRequests" -StartTime $timeminus1 -EndTime $timenow
############################################################################### Put DATA into Array ###########################################################################
$valuesFR = $azmetricFR.Data.Total
$namesFR = $azmetricFR.Name.Value | Out-String
############################################################################### LOOP - Send to Application Insights ###########################################################
foreach ($nameFR in $namesFR)
{
  foreach ($valueFR in $valuesFR)
     {
        $outputFR = $nameFR
        Write-Host $outputFR

        $client.TrackMetric($outputFR, $valueFR)
        $client.Flush()
    } 
}
############################################################################### Get DATA - ResponseStatus #####################################################################
$azmetricRS = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $env:resourceId -MetricName "ResponseStatus" -StartTime $timeminus1 -EndTime $timenow
############################################################################### Put DATA into Array ###########################################################################
$valuesRS = $azmetricRS.Data.Total
$namesRS = $azmetricRS.Name.Value | Out-String
############################################################################### LOOP - Send to Application Insights ###########################################################
foreach ($nameRS in $namesRS)
{
  foreach ($valueRS in $valuesRS)
     {
        $outputRS = $nameRS
        Write-Host $outputRS

        $client.TrackMetric($outputRS, $valueRS)
        $client.Flush()
    } 
}
############################################################################### Get DATA - CurrentConnections #################################################################
$azmetricCC = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $env:resourceId -MetricName "CurrentConnections" -StartTime $timeminus1 -EndTime $timenow
############################################################################### Put DATA into Array ###########################################################################
$valuesCC = $azmetricCC.Data.Total
$namesCC = $azmetricCC.Name.Value | Out-String
############################################################################### LOOP - Send to Application Insights ###########################################################
foreach ($nameCC in $namesCC)
{
  foreach ($valueCC in $valuesCC)
     {
        $outputCC = $nameCC
        Write-Host $outputCC

        $client.TrackMetric($outputCC, $valueCC)
        $client.Flush()
    } 
}
############################################################################### THE END #######################################################################################
```

As you can see, we have queried all metrics individually because it did not get better on the fast. I can't say if there is a cleaner solution.
With this data I could build alerts and dashboards.

I hope i gave you a better understanding for my problem.
This topic is solved unless you may have a better idea.

Regards

Comment: the metric times are going to be wrong, aren't they?  you're grabbing only total and value, but not what time that metric value occurred in the original source?  any delay in data is going to mean that stuff that as was delayed by 5 minutes doesn't get shown AT ALL by your script, because your script is always just doing a minute ago to now, and reporting all those values as occurring right now when you send it to app insights? any metrics that are not near real time are going to get missed by your script entirely, your times are going to be all off based on any delay in ingestion.

Comment: Hi John, what I forgot to Mention was, that we run a function app in Azure with this script, running every Minute, so it should be okay, as I can see in Azure AI, entries from every Minute with varying values, so I assume it should be okay. what bothers me more is the fact, we are now trying to fetch all data, like shown below in my other post, and I don't get how to do this properly. Additionally the solution runs on AzureGermanCloud and we extract the metrics with AzureInternationalCloud, as AppInsights is not available in AzureGermanCloud. That's  the reason for alll this effort.